# update-alternatives: error: alternative link /usr/share/java/clojure.jar is already managed by clojure

Tags: java, update-alternatives

Having upgraded to 18.04, I get the error above when trying to reinstall this package (it also showed during the upgrade I think). It seems this package is a prerequisite for other packages such as `libappindicator` (or just pops up again when trying to install them). So I need it solved.

I have tried playing with update-alternatives to no avail. How would I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I used:

```
update-alternatives --remove
```

to remove all its settings for `name` clojure. After that I could reinstall without trouble, or at least no more error messages. I guess installing `libclojure-java` with apt should have some flag for overrunning the existing definitions though, which would have been more elegant.